# Devise gem registration model issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an age check for my users in which if they want to sign up for my app, they have to be a certain age.  I am using the devise gem, but created a method in my user model to check the age....I get an error stating that whatever I want to do they can't due to a nil class.  Basically i have a user, but the birth_date on the user is not saving.

Which tells me that where I am putting this logic is in the wrong place. However I'm not sure where.  I have a registration controller, and a user controller. I also have user model. I don't have a registration model, i'm wondering if either my method needs to be in a different model that I don't have? Or if i'm building it incorrectly.

My user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :age_restriction

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def age_restriction
    if (self.birth_date&.to_date + 18.years) < Date.today # assuming dob format is mm/dd/yy
      errors.add :birth_date, 'must be older than 18'
    end
  end
end
```

My registration model

```
Cass RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: :create
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: :update

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:bith_date, :first_name, :last_name])
    binding.pry
  end

  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:birth_date, :first_name, :last_name])
  end
end
```

The breakpoint I have in there, when I type in `devise_parameter_sanitizer` I get

```
 @permitted=
  {:sign_in=>[:email, :password, :remember_me],
   :sign_up=>
    [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :bith_date, :first_name, :last_name],
   :account_update=>[:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password]},
 @resource_name=:user>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo. It's currently, :bith_date. Fix that to `birth_date` and the model should be able to read the proper attribute.

It was nil, since you're checking for `self.birth_date`, while the param you permitted is `:bith_date`

Allow `:birth_date` in the sign_up_params.